# make a call responding to Onclick

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am  a new android developer, and i want to create an android application who make a call when I click the button.

My Layout xml is :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Selectionner l&apos;IMSI" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="SendMessage"
    android:text="call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The SendMessage Methode is defined in MainActivity.java  as :

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {

// do something to answer the button click

    Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:333");
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
    startActivity(callIntent);

}
```

And i added the permission in the manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"></uses-permission>
```

when I click the button the message "Unfortunately the application has stopped" appears ! How can I solve this probleme ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you declared in the xml `android:onClick="SendMessage"`, so your activity is expecting

`public void SendMessage(View view)`

not

`public void sendMessage(View view)`

Answer (score 0):

```
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            String phoneNumber = editText.getText().toString();
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```